# How do I take an input number and use it in Java?

Tags: java

I have a program that simulates the probability of winning a game of craps after an inputted number of games.

The command line should be:

```
         $java SimCraps 1000
```

How do I get my program to recognize the input number 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would parse your first command line argument. Create a text file named `SimCraps.java`

```
public class SimCraps { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println("You entered " + number);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No number provided");
        }
    }
}
```

You compile `SimCraps.class` from `Simcraps.java` like

```
javac SimCraps.java
```

Then you can run it like

```
java -cp . SimCraps 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

it is available via command line arguments to `main()` method

```
public static void main (String ar[]){
   //1000 will be at ar[0]
}
```

It will be available as `String` you might want to check [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and [`String#trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) methods